# using tkinter, when spaning 2 columns margin is added

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just started learning python's tkinter module today. I'm making a basic calculator for practice. Currently I'm just making the actual GUI for it and the '0' button has margin on each side of it and I'm unsure why. Like I said, I just started learning it today. Can someone tell me why this is happening and also how to make it not?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Looking at the 0, there is margin on the left and right of the button.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

#init tkinter
root = Tk()
#name program
root.title('PyCalc')

#function to call when button is pressed to add to input field
def add_input():
    return

#create an input field
Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

#put buttons where they should be
for x in range(15):
    button = Button(root, text=x, width=10, height=4, command=add_input)

    if x == 0:
        Button(root, text=x, width=20, height=4, command=add_input).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
    elif x > 9:
        if x == 10:
            Button(root, text='=', width=10, height=4).grid(row=4, column=2)
        elif x == 11:
            Button(root, text='+', width=10, height=4).grid(row=1, column=3)
        elif x == 12:
            Button(root, text='-', width=10, height=4).grid(row=2, column=3)
        elif x == 13:
            Button(root, text='x', width=10, height=4).grid(row=3, column=3)
        else:
            Button(root, text='/', width=10, height=4).grid(row=4, column=3)
    else:
        if x % 3 == 0:
            #9, 6, 3
            if 10 - x < 4:
                #9
                button.grid(row=1, column=2)
            elif 10 - x in [4, 5, 6]:
                #6
                button.grid(row=2, column=2)
            else:
                #3
                button.grid(row=3, column=2)
        elif 10 - x in [2, 5, 8]:
            #8, 5, 2
            if 10 - x < 4:
                #8
                button.grid(row=1, column=1)
            elif 10 - x in [4, 5, 6]:
                #5
                button.grid(row=2, column=1)
            else:
                #2
                button.grid(row=3, column=1)
        else:
            #7, 4, 1
            if 10 - x < 4:
                #7
                button.grid(row=1, column=0)
            elif 10 - x in [4, 5, 6]:
                #4
                button.grid(row=2, column=0)
            else:
                #1
                button.grid(row=3, column=0)

#run it
root.mainloop()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a widget (in this case a button) to the grid, you can add the `sticky`parameter to make the button expand to fill the grid in any given direction. In this case, if you changed to:

```
Button(root, text=x, width=20, height=4, command=add_input).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)
```

That would fix it. `tkinter.EW` is a built in TKinter shortcut for `tkinter.E + tkinter.W`, which is saying to expand to fill to the East and to the West.

EDIT:

Also, I just noticed you're creating extra buttons when x is less than 9 but never adding them to the grid. Is this on purpose? You should be able to do what you did for when x is greater than or equal to 9 and call `grid()` on the pre-existing button.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll give that a go and see how it works! As for the buttons you're referring to, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the 0 & 9-14 buttons? They are being added to the grid, I just chained the .grid to the end of them. Not for any reason, just happened to do that for some reason lol

Comment: That did indeed fix it! Thank you so much! Do you know any good resources off the top of your head for tkinter? All good if you don't!

Comment: @CodyLee _Off the top_??

Comment: I was referring to the 0-8 buttons. You instantiate a button and store it in the `button` variable on line 17, but then you seem to create new buttons to add to the grid. This means you're making a "ghost button" that never gets placed on the grid for each of those buttons. For the 9-14 buttons, you're correctly adding the button stored in the `button` variable to the grid. As for resources, I typically use [tkdocs](https://tkdocs.com/), though I admit the documentation can be frustrating at times.

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I see what you're saying. I didn't realize that would do that. I did that just to reduce character count so it looked a bit neater. I'll change it! Thanks for the catch! @Cool Cloud, like off the top of your head. So like readily available kind of thing.

Comment: [This pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XRTgym9B) has what I would consider a "fixed" version, if you want it (also because I'm bored).

Comment: Readily available? Well....take a look at `ttkthemes`. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325559/how-to-set-a-style-to-my-whole-tkinter-app/63326642#63326642) to know how to apple them :)